# d3.js does not update one specific property when data changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 4 circles with a radius of 70px upon `enter`.

```
function draw_circles(...){ 


    data = get_random_generador_data(); 
    //the data contains the circle coordinates, as well 
    // as the radius, the text or the fill color.

    var circleGroup = svgContainer.selectAll('g').data(data);

   //=======
   //ENTER
   //=======
   var circleGroupEnter = circleGroup
       .enter()
       .append('g')
       .attr("id",  function(d) { return "group_"+d["ix"]; })

   circleGroupEnter
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d["cx"]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d["cy"]; })
      .attr("r",  function(d) { return d["rad"]; })
      .attr("id",  function(d) { return "circle_"+d["ix"]; }) //this is 70
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d["fill_color"]; })
;


   //=======
   //UPDATE
   //=======
   circleGroup.select("circle")
        .attr("cx",    function(d) { return d["cx"]; })
        .attr("cy",    function(d) { return d["cy"]; })
        .attr("r",     function(d) { return 2.0* d["rad"]; })
        .attr("id",    function(d) { return "circle_"+d["ix"]; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d["fill_color"]; })
```

**AFTER ENTER**
[image: after enter is called]

Now, if the user performs a click in one specific one of them, I change the radius of that one to 1.5*70 and call draw_circles again. This generates a new set of data so the `update` part will be called.

```
d3.select('#'+c_id)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration_till_next)
                    .attr("r",     function(d) { return 1.50* d["rad"]; })
```

After this I get:

**AFTER CLICK**
[image]

This works as expected. Now, I have a `setTimeout` and after a couple of seconds, `draw_circles` gets called again from within itself, getting new data and triggering the `update` part of the d3 code above.

**BUT!** on the `update` part of the code, I change the radius to 140px, as you can see on the line above `.attr("r",     function(d) { return 2.0* d["rad"]; })`

```
setTimeout(function(){ draw_circles(...);}, 2000);
```

**AFTER UPDATE**:
[image]

So as you can see, there is one element for which the radius update was not applied. However, all the other properties of the circle **were** changed, such as the coordinates in the image, the text inside of it or the fill color. Only the radius change is not observed.

Now it cannot be a coincidence that the property I happen to modify ad hoc is the very same one that doesn't get updated, but I cannot understand why.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Ok so the issue is here:

```
d3.select('#'+c_id)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration_till_next)
                    .attr("r",     function(d) { return 1.50* d["rad"]; })

 setTimeout(function(){ draw_circles(...);}, 2000);
```

The issue is that `duration_till_next` is also 2000.  So what seems to be happening is that by the time the circles are updated, the circle has not finished transitioning. I would have expected that changing the circle radius is finished first, since it's supposed to be called first.

This makes the problem disappear:

```
.duration(0.9 * duration_till_next)
```

but this doesn't

```
.duration(0.99 * duration_till_next)
```

So there seems to be some sort of race going on.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behaviour you described but I failed: all my circles are changing. So, at this point, I believe the best idea is creating a working fiddle/codepen/plunker/whatever with the behaviour you described.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a go, thanks

Comment: Hi, as it turns out, adding a transition on the `update` with a duration of even 1 ms fixes the issue, which leads me to believe this is some sort of issue with asynchronicity

Comment: Well, I still would like to see a code reproducing that behaviour, just to check *why* it happened. Right now you solved it, but you can't explain what happened, can you?

Comment: actually this steered me in the right direction, got it now.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: See my edit. Apologies for not providing the fiddle, it's actually a bit of work getting it done.

Comment: There is no need for it, I believe your edit clarified the issue.

Comment: Well I'm still not 100% percent of why the behaviour is what I observe, I still need to think about it a bit more.